# unable to res.json the list of msg sent using twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, twilio

```
router.get(
  "/send",
  async (req, res) => {
    client.messages
      .list({ limit: 20 })
      .then((messages) => messages.forEach((m) => console.log(m.body)));
  });
```

i am using twilio and want to `res.json(m.body)` .  The problem is , it will only do for first element (as expected from res.json). Its probably very trivial but i have tried push, spread operator and am unable to come up with solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't call `res.json(m.body)` on each message, because the first time you call `res.json` Express will complete the response.

Try something like:

```js
router.get(
  "/send",
  async (req, res) => {
    client.messages
      .list({ limit: 20 })
      .then((messages) => res.json(messages.map((m) => m.body)));
  });
```

This maps the list of messages to a list of the message bodies and returns the whole list with `res.json`.

Edit:

If you want to save the list of `m.body` and `m.to` to a variable to be used later, you can do something like this:

```js
router.get("/send", async (req, res) => {
  client.messages.list({ limit: 20 }).then((messages) => {
    const data = messages.map((m) => ({ body: m.body, to: m.to }));
    res.json(data);
  });
});
```

In this case we map over the messages turning them into an array of objects with `to` and `body` keys. That array is then assigned to the `data` variable, which we then use later to return with `res.json(data)`.

Comment: thank you so much for answering this, esp from twillo developer himself . if you dont mind , can you tell how can we save such list of "m.body" and "m.to" in a variable and res.json that variable instead . i wanna learn for future . thank you in advance.

Comment: Edited my answer with an example of how to do that.